# Error in PHP Mail_Queue PEAR library

Tags: php, email, mail-queue

I'm getting the following error when trying to use the PHP `Mail_Queue` PEAR library:

Declaration of `Mail_Queue::isError()` should be compatible with that of `PEAR::isError()`

PHP 5.2.3, Mail Queue Version 1.2.3

Searching on Google hasn't turned up anything. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Surely too late but I resolved this issue by modifying the Mail/Queue.php file
The declaration of `Mail_Queue::isError` should match exactly the one provided in `PEAR::isError` which takes two arguments.

So, changing (line 584 for release 1.2.6) :

```
function isError($value)
```

To :

```
function isError($value, $dummy = "")
```

Solves the warning.
It is not 100% satisfying because this modification will disappear while next update but it saved my day (0% error & warning)

Comment: Great! This helped me out. I wonder why this has not been fixed?